# JTL file result is contradicted with actual test result

Tags: jmeter

In JMeter JTL file result contradicts actual test result.

Actually post completion of my test plan, when I checked my database table the count is accurate regarding the test I ran.

But when I cross check the generated *.jtl file for same test plan then I found that there is in most labels response code and response message is '500' and 'Internal Server Error' respectively.

While it should be '200' and 'OK' for all as my table shows accurate result as I want.

Please do needful as I am beginner in JMeter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with provided informations it is hard to say but there can be a lot of reasons among which:

- you db insert occurs before a later error  you application that would explain why you have correct data in Database
- you are not looking at all data written by your app, only looking at part of it

Try displaying error responses you get to see what error can be.

You can use Simple data writer listener for this.